# useeffect is not calling 2nd time in React, how to resolve this?

Tags: reactjs

useEffect is not calling 2nd render how can we do that using Recat?I tried putting dependecncy item still it's not working.Even with [] it' not working

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

That is the intended behaviour of using `[]`, it will only be called when the component is created. Without seeing your code my best guess is that the 'dependency' is not actually updating. [UseEffect docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```js
[myState,setMyState] = useState(0)

useEffect(()=>{
// i get called on mount only
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
// i get called after myState is changed via setMyState
},[myState])
```